# The Delay of uploading documents

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload

One of my team members has a questions. Is there any way we set an automatic upload of a document or is there a way we can delay making that document public until a certain time?

Regards,

Comment: draft and publish should work well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, using Approval Workflows.

[Microsoft Documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/All-about-Approval-workflows-078c5a89-821f-44a9-9530-40bb34f9f742)

Or just use draft/publish etc

[Plan document versioning, content approval, and check-out controls in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262378.aspx)